# How to complete interactive UIViewController transition?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I've been dabbling with the new iOS 7 custom transition API and looked through all the tutorials/documentation I could find but I can't seem to figure this stuff out for my specific scenario.

So essentially what I'm trying to implement is a UIPanGestureRecognizer on a view where I would swipe up and transition to a VC whose view would slide up from the bottom while the current view would slide up as I drag my finger higher.

I have no problem accomplishing this without the interaction transition, but once I implement the interaction (the pan gesture) I can't seem to complete the transition.

**Here's the relevant code from the VC that conforms to the UIViewControllerTransitionDelegate which is needed to vend the animator controllers:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Swipe"]) {
        NSLog(@"PREPARE FOR SEGUE METHOD CALLED");

        UIViewController *toVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        [interactionController wireToViewController:toVC];
        toVC.transitioningDelegate = self;
        toVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
      }
}

#pragma mark UIViewControllerTransition Delegate Methods

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:  (UIViewController *)presented                                                                   presentingController:  (UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    NSLog(@"PRESENTING ANIMATION CONTROLLER CALLED");

    SwipeDownPresentationAnimationController *transitionController = [SwipeDownPresentationAnimationController new];
    return transitionController;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    NSLog(@"DISMISS ANIMATION CONTROLLER CALLED");

    DismissAnimatorViewController *transitionController = [DismissAnimatorViewController new];
    return transitionController;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForDismissal:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator {
    NSLog(@"Interaction controller for dimiss method caled");

    return interactionController.interactionInProgress ? interactionController:nil;
}
```

**NOTE: The interaction swipe is only for the dismissal of the VC which is why it's in the interactionControllerForDismissal method**

**Here's the code for the animator of the dismissal which works fine when I tap on a button to dismiss it:**

```
#import "DismissAnimatorViewController.h"

@implementation DismissAnimatorViewController

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 1.0;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];

    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    CGRect initialFrameFromVC = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromVC];

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    NSLog(@"The screen bounds is :%@", NSStringFromCGRect(screenBounds));
    toVC.view.frame = CGRectOffset(initialFrameFromVC, 0, screenBounds.size.height);
    toVC.view.alpha = 0.2;

    CGRect pushedPresentingFrame = CGRectOffset(initialFrameFromVC, 0, -screenBounds.size.height);

    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.6
          initialSpringVelocity:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         fromVC.view.frame = pushedPresentingFrame;
                         fromVC.view.alpha = 0.2;
                         toVC.view.frame = initialFrameFromVC;
                         toVC.view.alpha = 1.0;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
}

@end
```

**Here's the code for the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition subclass which serves as the interaction controller:**

```
#import "SwipeInteractionController.h"

@implementation SwipeInteractionController {
    BOOL _shouldCompleteTransition;
    UIViewController *_viewController;
}

- (void)wireToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    _viewController = viewController;
    [self prepareGestureRecognizerInView:_viewController.view];
}

- (void)prepareGestureRecognizerInView:(UIView*)view {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    gesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1.0;

    [view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (CGFloat)completionSpeed {
    return 1 - self.percentComplete;
    NSLog(@"PERCENT COMPLETE:%f",self.percentComplete);
}

- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
//    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:gestureRecognizer.view.superview];
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:gestureRecognizer.view.superview];

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            // 1. Start an interactive transition!
            self.interactionInProgress = YES;
            [_viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            // 2. compute the current position
            CGFloat fraction = fabsf(translation.y / 568);
            NSLog(@"Fraction is %f",fraction);
            fraction = fminf(fraction, 1.0);
            fraction = fmaxf(fraction, 0.0);
            // 3. should we complete?
            _shouldCompleteTransition = (fraction > 0.23);
            // 4. update the animation controller
            [self updateInteractiveTransition:fraction];
            NSLog(@"Percent complete:%f",self.percentComplete);
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled: {
            // 5. finish or cancel
            NSLog(@"UI GESTURE RECOGNIZER STATE CANCELED");
            self.interactionInProgress = NO;
            if (!_shouldCompleteTransition || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
                [self cancelInteractiveTransition];
                NSLog(@"Interactive Transition is cancled.");
                }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Interactive Transition is FINISHED");
                [self finishInteractiveTransition];
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            NSLog(@"Default is being called");
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

**Once again, when I run the code now and I don't swipe all the way to purposefully cancel the transition, I just get a flash and am presented with the view controller I want to swipe to. This happens regardless if the transition completes or is canceled.**

**However, when I dismiss via the button I get the transition specified in my animator view controller.**

Comment: Make sure to override the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` methods for beginning, ending, and updating the animation. I don't see them implemented anywhere in your code.

Comment: @AshFurrow: I did read your Teehan+Lax tutorial on custom transitions where you mentioned overriding the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` methods, but what I don't get is the reason for it. Is it necessary? I'm currently in the middle of an implementation without it, and admittedly I am getting some weird behaviour (e.g. finishing animations repeat again from the percentage at where the gesture ended _after_ initial finish, screen going black after interactive cancel), but I'm not 100% sure that's the cause. Anyhoo, just wondering if you had a reason for the overrides. Thanks!

Comment: Overriding `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` is not strictly necessary, but it's the easiest and "Apple friendly" approach.

Comment: For some reasons, overriding the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition Methods fixed the problem, at least for my case wherein the fromVC freezes if the Transition has been cancelled.

Comment: Stuck with the same problem. Completion block never get called neither transition completed nor it was canceled. ios8. Have you found the way, how to solve this?

Answer (score 22):

I can see a couple of issues here - although I cannot be certain that these will fix your problem!

Firstly, your animation controller's UIView animation completion block has the following:

```
[transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
```

Whereas it should return completion based on the result of the interaction controller as follows:

```
[transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]]
```

Also, I have found that if you tell the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` that a transition is 100% complete, it does not call the animation controller completion block. As a workaround, I limit it to ~99.9%

https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary/issues/4

I've created a number of example interaction and animation controllers here, that you might find useful:

https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary

Comment: Thanks for the help Colin. I tried what you had said, but still have the problem. Hmm..

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I tried the fixes above and others, but nothing worked. Then I stumbled upon https://github.com/MrAlek/AWPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, which fixed everything.

Once you add it to your project, just replace `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` with `AWPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

Also, you have to set the animator before starting an interactive transition. In my case, I use the same class for `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning`, so I just did it in `init()`:

```
init() {
    super.init()
    self.animator = self
}
```